# CPU-Z, Bios and Windows all recognize other memory

Tags: memory, motherboard, bios

My 16gb DDR3 arrived today (didn't have money to upgrade motherboard to DDR4). When I pulled out my other memory and put this one in it did the three beep "No memory detected" thing that Asus motherboards do. So I added back the other two RAM sticks I have and looked in Windows if the new stick can be found, downloaded CPU-Z and checked the BIOS:

- CPU-Z detects my new RAM
- Windows detects only my 2 old RAM sticks
- BIOS detects all memory

Also, I had a problem earlier where my RAM didn't work with others, after which I gave up and just removed the 2x2gb sticks I had from my previous setup.

What can be the reason different software detects different hardware? Shouldn't Windows and CPU-Z get their information from the BIOS?

**Setup:**

- Asus B150M-A D3
- Intel Core i7-6700
- Sapphire Dual-X R7 265
- Crucial 8GB PC3-12800 (2x4gb)
- Hewlett Packard Enterprise DDR3 16gb (1x16gb) (Recognized as Samsung? Guess they made it?)
- Corsair VS450

**CPU-Z:**

[image]

**CPU-Z only detects slot 3:**

[image]

Windows:

[image]

BIOS:

[image]

Comment: In your BIOS screenshot it is showing it but it isn’t using it. See above, it says Memory: 8192MB. Start by confirming the memory is on the Asus QVL and that you have set all memory settings to default/auto and you are not trying to overclock anything.

Comment: Tried to use the RAM on another PC, and it also didn't work. @Vedant helped me and it seems it's defect.

Answer (score 0):

The RAM slots are color coded. Use the 2x 4GB in the same color. And the 16GB in the other colored slot.

EDIT: please refer to [this](https://itstillworks.com/12313422/how-to-change-your-bios-after-adding-ram)

Comment: I actually only want to use the 16GB. Put the other ones back in because it wouldn't start. I do see two different colored slots, so let me just try it.

Comment: @ScubaKay It is actually recommended to use RAM in pairs as they complement each other. Try placing the 16GB in all the color slots.

Comment: The 16GB doens't work on it's own. I get the three beeps saying memory not detected. I have grey and black slots. When I place my 2x4gb in one and the 16gb in another, it doesn't do anything. No beeps whatsoever.

Comment: @ScubaKay in all slots?

Comment: Yes, in all slots.

Comment: @ScubaKay use one 4 Gb and 16 gb in same color and then different color

Comment: @ScubaKay run CPU-Z as admin

Comment: @ScubaKay see update in the answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69012/discussion-between-scuba-kay-and-vedant).